# Is any explanation offered for the anime’s ending regarding lost bodily function?

Tags: yuki-yuna-is-a-hero

**Warning: Major spoilers following.**
(Yes, I'm aware the anime is 'old news', but the spoiler warning doesn't hurt.)

It is established in the anime that the heros of the Taisha can 'bloom' to increase their strength, and that

> this 'blooming' causes them to lose a bodily function (one eye's vision, taste, voice, one ear’s hearing) upon returning to the everyday world.
>
>  Similarly, from Tougou's and Yuuna's meeting with the former hero, it is established that this process seems irreversible because they are 'offerings to the divine tree'.

However, during the last episode,

> despite having bloomed multiple times (and in Karin's case, having a part of her body 'chained' each time), the girls regain the bodily functions they have lost — and even those they lost in the former bloomings, i.e. in Tougou's case she can even move her legs again.

Is there any explanation given either in the anime itself (which I must have missed) or in derived works as to how what is put into the second spoiler box is even possible? It seems to contradict everything we learnt about the hero system in the preceeding episodes.

Comment: There are many secondary/derived works for YuYuYu (a PS Vita game + multiple LNs/manga); I suspect the answer is probably in there somewhere. I haven't gotten around to most of them yet, though, so I don't have an answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the bonus chapter 「その後の園子」 (*Sono Ato no Sonoko*, [Sonoko After](http://yuyuyu.wikia.com/wiki/Sonoko_After)), published on *Dengeki G's magazine* ed. 2015/03.

The story talks about the everyday life of Nogi Sonoko and the heroes after the final battle. It also explains the reason why the divine tree decided to "reverse the effect".

Excerpt from the script (***possible spoiler for 2nd season***, heavily redacted to answer the question only):

> After the party, Sonoko went over to Tougou's house. Yuuna was probably being considerate. Today, she left them alone. The two had a lot to talk about.
>  About everything that's happened so far.
>  About their dear friend.
>  And...
>  "Have you heard the reason everyone's getting their offerings back, Sonocchi?"
>  The other side of the incident.
>  Sonoko smiled.
>
>  [...]
>
>  "The Shinju-sama... came to believe in human courage~"
>
>  [...]
>
>  "However the Shinju-sama came to believe in the courage of mankind. By witnessing Yu~yu's and everyone's hard work, as well as getting plenty of Vertex combat data, the hero system was updated to the next stage."
>
>  [...]
>
>  "Don't think negatively about the situation. The Shinju-sama believed mankind would be able to walk down the harsh path, instead of a gentle one that lead to its demise. That is why it gave back our offerings and allowed for mass-production of the system so that everyone would be able to stand and fight. Everyone will don their own flower~. Isn't that a good thing?"

Answer (score 1):

When they bloom, the girls' bodily functions aren't *lost*, per se, but are "given" to the divine tree as an offering. At the end of the series, the divine tree elects to return what it took (i don't remember if the reasoning was expressly stated or not, but I like to think that it realized the extreme detrimental effect this was having on the girls).

Comment: How do you know this? Is there any evidence for your claim?

Comment: Was this not how they explained it in-show? I apologize if I was incorrect, i simply explained it as I remembered it. (The last parenthetical statement is merely my headcanon though.)

Comment: If it was explained in show, state so, preferably by whom. This counts as a fact. If it wasn't then it is an opinion and not an answer. I am simply stating your answer is insufficient as one right now.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm going to double-check that episode and edit my answer.

Comment: You're so close to the real answer. I wish you can backup this answer by providing any sources/references (the episode you mentioned)...